# Filtering and sorting in combobox column of RadGridView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

RadGridView is binded to some collection where some properties represent some key values.
I've added combobox columns which are binded to these properties and added itemssource which contains key-displayValue pairs.

The question is how to setup sorting and filtering by display value?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter or sort with a `CollectionViewSource`. `CollectionViewSource` is a data binding infrastructure to provide the features like filtering and Sorting.

**How to initialize CollectionView :**

```
ICollectionView _collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(<<ItemsSource bind to comboBox>>);
```

**Filtering**

To filter a collection view you can define a callback method that determines if the item should be part of the view or not. That method should have the following signature: `bool Filter(object item)`. Now set the delegate of that method to the Filter property of the CollectionView and you're done

**Sorting**

Sorting data ascending or descending by one or multiple criteria is a common requirement for viewing data. The collection view makes it so easy to achieve this goal. Just add as many `SortDescriptions` as you like to the CollectionView